# Non member comparison operator for a template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-keyword, non-member-functions

I have defined a template container `Tree<T>`, with two member-class iterators : `const_iterator` and `iterator`

Now I would like to add non member comparison operators:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(Tree<T>::const_iterator a, Tree<T>::iterator b)
{
    return a.ptr() == b.ptr();
}
```

But I have the compilation error:

```
declaration of 'operator==' as non-function
```

Why? Is this due to the template?

Comment: Even with missing `typename`, your overload cannot be really used as `T` cannot be deduced. The way to go is to add a friend `operator ==` inside `Tree<T>::const_iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `typename` for the [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) here, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(typename Tree<T>::const_iterator a, typename Tree<T>::iterator b)
//              ~~~~~~~~                            ~~~~~~~~
{
    return a.ptr() == b.ptr();
}
```

Comment: Argh. The error message was not very explicit. Thanks

Comment: @galinette Unfortunately it's common for templates.